# functional method vs normal method in class

Tags: java, java-8

What is the difference of using **function method (closure)** and **normal java method** when not using this functional method within a method itself. Any other benefits (e.g. faster access speed)?

version 1:

```
public class Test{

    // does not need to be consumer, can also be 
    // own function (see version 3)
    public static final Consumer<User> addUser = s -> {
        // the same logic as in version 2
    };
}
```

version 2:

```
public class Test{
    public static final void addUser(User u) {
        // the same logic as in version 1
    }
}
```

version 3:

```
public class Test{

Function<User, String> addUser= (User e)-> {/* the same logic as in version 2 */;return "saved";};
}
```

Comment: In the first case you cannot call `Test.addUser` but in second case you can. There is nothing more to it. The benefit of Java8 functional support is that you can wrap `Test.addUser` into an object pass around.

Comment: Often the issue of program clarity, readability, is far more important to the life-cycle of a piece of code than the number of clock cycles. The difference in execution I'm guessing is not as significant here, except for the additional flexibility given by using Function.

Comment: @tsolakp "you can wrap Test.addUser into an object pass around". Any example for that?

Comment: @nimo23 Here `Consumer<User> addUser = Test::addUser;` the `addUser` is the object wrapping `Test.addUser` method.

Comment: @Eugene the method reference in turn becomes an instance of "anonymous" class that "wraps" the call to `Test.addUser`. You can call it something else.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a decent compiler will inline this anyway, especially due to the `static final` declaration.

Comment: @Izruo `final` will make it a mono-morphic method that AFAIK has nothing to do with inlining, methods that are inlined depend on the size and frequency of calls.

Comment: @Eugene I was referring to the field, not the method. The `static final` makes pretty sure, its content isn't going to change, so why not inline it directly? Although we shouldn't make assumptions what a compiler does and what it does not ...

Comment: @Izruo: the optimizer may use the field’s `final` modifier as a hint, but up to date JVMs will inline the code anyway, using the optimistic assumption that the field does not change and de-optimize if the field does change. So the difference imposed by `final` is tiny. But your assumption that it will likely get inlined is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time you invoke your `Consumer` it will be slower, because your lambda expression will spin a class underneath that will implement `Consumer::accept` with the logic that you provided, but that happens only once on the first call.

You can pass around a `Consumer` for example, but you can't a method. Well, there are MethodHandles that allow to pass a *pointer/reference* to a method.

Comment: I can also write my own closure, does not need to be a Consumer. For example, `public static final addUser = s -> {
        // the same logic as in version 2
};`

Comment: @nimo23 `public static final addUser = s -> {...}` makes no sense. It has to be some type and it does not have to a be `Consumer`. A *lambda* is transformed to a class (which of course is an implementation detail)

Comment: yes, right. I only wanted to show that closures does not need to have java8-consumer/producer.

Comment: @nimo23 it seems that you do not understand what you actually what to know, as `Function<User> addUser` does not exist, a `Function` takes two generic types: `Function<T,R>` If you don't understand what you want, how can we?